# How to create a Gnosis Safe locally with hardhat safe-tasks

Tags: hardhat, gnosis-safe, safe-core-sdk

I am trying to utilize the safe-tasks hardhat library to create a Safe with a locally deployed Safe protocol.

But I am getting the following error, and as I understand it fails on the stage of reading pure function from the contract (By the way, the address TO matches with locally deployed)

```
nhavr2@C02FN45UMD6M safe-tasks % yarn safe create --l2 
yarn run v1.22.19
$ hardhat create --l2
An unexpected error occurred:

Error: call revert exception (method="proxyCreationCode()", errorSignature=null, errorArgs=[null], reason=null, code=CALL_EXCEPTION, version=abi/5.1.0)
    at Logger.makeError (/Users/nhavr2/DEV/Blockchain/safe-tasks/node_modules/@ethersproject/logger/src.ts/index.ts:205:28)
    at Logger.throwError (/Users/nhavr2/DEV/Blockchain/safe-tasks/node_modules/@ethersproject/logger/src.ts/index.ts:217:20)
    at Interface.decodeFunctionResult (/Users/nhavr2/DEV/Blockchain/safe-tasks/node_modules/@ethersproject/abi/src.ts/interface.ts:326:23)
    at Contract.<anonymous> (/Users/nhavr2/DEV/Blockchain/safe-tasks/node_modules/@ethersproject/contracts/src.ts/index.ts:321:44)
    at step (/Users/nhavr2/DEV/Blockchain/safe-tasks/node_modules/@ethersproject/contracts/lib/index.js:48:23)
    at Object.next (/Users/nhavr2/DEV/Blockchain/safe-tasks/node_modules/@ethersproject/contracts/lib/index.js:29:53)
    at fulfilled (/Users/nhavr2/DEV/Blockchain/safe-tasks/node_modules/@ethersproject/contracts/lib/index.js:20:58)
    at processTicksAndRejections (node:internal/process/task_queues:94:5) {
  reason: null,
  code: 'CALL_EXCEPTION',
  method: 'proxyCreationCode()',
  errorSignature: null,
  errorArgs: [ null ],
  address: '0xa6B71E26C5e0845f74c812102Ca7114b6a896AB2',
  args: [],
  transaction: {
    data: '0x53e5d935',
    to: '0xa6B71E26C5e0845f74c812102Ca7114b6a896AB2',
    from: '0xf39Fd6e51aad88F6F4ce6aB8827279cffFb92266',
    gasLimit: BigNumber { _hex: '0x05e6f1d8', _isBigNumber: true }
  }
}
error Command failed with exit code 1.
info Visit https://yarnpkg.com/en/docs/cli/run for documentation about this command.
```